# How to make Traditional Pos a Cloud Pos?

Tags: java, swing, pos

I have created a traditional POS using Java Swing in which Users can access data only on the system in which data is stored. Now I want to access data anywhere at any time by the user. How can I make my traditional pos a cloud pos?

Comment: How are you storing the data?  Databases exist in the cloud.

Comment: Now I am storing data in xampp installed locally, not in the cloud.